# break sql query results down into half hour sections

Tags: mysql, sql, repeat

I have a query

```
SELECT count(dayofweek(created)) FROM `rental` 
WHERE dayofweek(created) < 6
AND time(created) between "10:00:00" and "10:30:00"
```

I am repeating the query for ever half hour increment of the day to see what the busiest times are ie number of rentals in that period.

Is there a way to do the whole thing as 1 query ie output something like this:

```
period 1 | 1200
period 2 | 2130
period 3 | 2453
```

etc?

At the moment I am repeating it over and over and is quite tedious...
Thanks

Comment: Please add the appropriate sql tag, e.g. `sql-server`, `mysql`, `oracle` etc

Answer (score 0):

My best cross-dbms approach would be that of adding a column to the table "rental" containing an integer representing the value time(created) as 30 minutes slots (i.e. 0 = 1 jan 1970 00:00:00 to 00:29:59, 1 = 1 jan 1970 00:30:00 to 00:59:59, 2 = 1 jan 1970 01:00:00 to 01:29:59 -- this is very simple to do, basically it's timestamp / 30000 rounded down) and then use that field to group the values.

You could do the division on the fly but this would create problems with the group by on some DBMSs, this solution is more scalable and fully compatible with virtually any dbms.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

here your are a definition in SQL Server syntax

```
DECLARE @startTime SMALLDATETIME = '2013-12-30 00:00:00';
DECLARE @stopTime SMALLDATETIME = '2014-01-10 00:00:00';

WITH intervals(IntervalNo, intervalStart, dayNo)
AS
(
    SELECT 0, @startTime, datepart(dw, @startTime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT intervals.IntervalNo + 1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, intervals.intervalStart), datepart(dw, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, intervals.intervalStart))
    FROM intervals 
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, intervals.intervalStart) < @stopTime
) 
SELECT 'period'+CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startTime, r.created) / 30 as VARCHAR(10)), COUNT(r.created)
FROM intervals i 
INNER JOIN rental r
    ON i.dayNo = datepart(dw, r.created) AND i.IntervalNo = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startTime, r.created) / 30 AND i.dayNo < 6
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startTime, r.created) / 30
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Hi I am using MYSQL 5 - your code is giving me a syntax error but cant figure out where exactly..

Comment: yes... this is SQL Server syntax
I have added mysql tag to your question

Comment: Thanks - I am getting this error though:
SQL query:

DECLARE @startTime SMALLDATETIME = '2013-12-30 00:00:00';


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE ...at line 1